# calender running infinite loop

Tags: c++, controls, infinite-loop

The code for outputting calender works fine but it isn't showing required number of spaces for each month. Suppose if January ends on Friday, Feb should start from Saturday.

To keep count of that I have added a `line` variable that gives required number of spaces whenever a new month starts by looking at start day i.e. `sd`.

So after each month I have to initialize `line` to 1 to make space for next month but initializing line to 1 is running an infinite loop.

```
while (month <= 12)
{
  if (month == 2)
    days = 28;

  else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
    days = 30;

  else days = 31;

  cout << endl << endl << endl;

  if (month == 1)
    cout << "      JANUARY 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 2)
    cout << "      FEBRUARY 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 3)
    cout << "      MARCH 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 4)
    cout << "      APRIL 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 5)
    cout << "      MAY 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 6)
    cout << "      JUNE 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 7)
    cout << "      JULY 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 8)
    cout << "      AUGUST 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 9)
    cout << "      SEPTEMBER 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 10)
    cout << "      OCTOBER 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 11)
    cout << "      NOV 20XX    \n";

  else if (month == 12)
    cout << "      DEC 20XX    \n";

  cout << "-   -   -   -   -   -   -\n";
  cout << "M   T   W   T   F   S   S\n";
  cout << "-   -   -   -   -   -   -\n";

  while (j < days) {
    for (i = 0; i < 7
         && j <= days; i++) { //i from 0to 6 for 7 days.j from 1 to no. of
      //days in the month
      if ((line == 1) && (i < sd))     //line =1 so that space is only in first line
        cout << "    ";

      else {
        cout << j << "  ";
        j++;

        if (i == 6) {
          cout << endl;
          line++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (i == 7)
    sd = 1;

  else sd = i + 1;

  cout << sd;
  month++;
  j = 1;
  i = 0;
  line = 1; //infinite loop here!On removing line=1, it works fine except spaces.
}
```

Comment: Haven't you ever heard of arrays.  Or even switches?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the variables are not being initialised. [This works fine, as you say, just with the incorrect spaces](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2c716cb09d93e6b)

You haven't post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but be sure to declare and initialise your loop variables, something like:

```
int month = 0;
int line = 0;
int days = 0;
int j = 0;
int i = 0;
int sd = 0;
```

Comment: I agree with this. Because of a lack of MCVE, I had to build my own and because of this, I cannot be sure that my version (which seems to work, by the way) is the same as OP's.

Comment: @DavidFrye. Same here, the only assumptions I made where the type of the looping variables, just set them to `0` as I normally would and it all looked to work ok. From the look of the code, I figure this smells a lot like other "variable initialisation problems" I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

In the code extract below:

```
while (j < days) {
for (i = 0; i < 7 && j <= days; i++) { 
  if ((line == 1) && (i < sd))     
    // The above if statement is false if 'line != 1' or 'i >= sd'.
  else {
    // 'line' is incremented in here. Hence this code will only be
    // executed if the preceding if-statement is terminated via the 'i < sd' condition.
  }
```

I suspect `i` never becomes `>= sd`. What is the value of `sd`?

If `sd` is bigger or equal to `7`, you have a problem.

`for (i = 0; i < 7 && j <= days; i++)` will terminate on `i < 7` before the `i < sd` condition in `if ((line == 1) && (i < sd))` is ever false, since `line` is stuck on `1` and `i` never gets bigger than 6 due to the outer `for-loop` termination-condition.

`j <= days` will stay true since the code that increments `j` is never executed.

Comment: If you have a condition on `A && B` it becomes false when EITHER `!A` OR `!B`. Thus everything you said does not hold, both for the `if` and for the `for`.

Comment: @Svalorzen, True, but my argument is that neither `line == 1` nor `i < sd` ever becomes false before the outer `for-loop` condition `i < 7` becomes false. Hence `line` and `j` is never incremented.